# Updating many objects with one form

Tags: python, django

I am building a shopping cart. I have a `Product` model and a `ShoppingCartItem` model:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    price_per_unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    image = StdImageField(default="default.jpg", variations={
        'thumbnail': {"width": 100, "height": 100, "crop": True}
    })

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ShoppingCartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(django_settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='cart_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product  = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    # Update the quantity of an item in the shopping cart
    def update_quantity(self, quantity):
        if quantity <= 0:
            # If user sets quantity to 0 or less, delete the item.
            self.remove_item()
        else:
            self.quantity = quantity
            self.save()

    # Remove item from the shopping cart
    def remove_item(self):
        self.delete()

    def get_ext_total(self):
        return Decimal(self.product.price_per_unit * self.quantity)
```

I want the UX to be able to update quantities via a text box for many `ShoppingCartItem`s at a time. I've looked at formsets and inline formsets but they appear to be more suited to the creation of objects and ManyToMany relationships from within each object rather than updating many objects at one time. Below is an example of my shopping cart:

[image: Shopping Cart List]

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not a good idea to make multiple queries for updating database and you want to update multiple objects attribute in a single call. But, if the attribute values are different, there is no simple way to do it in ORM.

You can implement one of the below:

## Single Update

Generally, single update using primary is very fast in database and If number of update are not that high this is good enough.

```
def update_cart(user_id, cart):
   for product_id, quantity in cart.items():
       ShoppingCartItem.objects.get(user__id=user_id, product__id=product_id).update(quantity=quantity)
```

## Single Update using Transaction

```
from django.db import transaction
    def update_cart(user_id, cart):
        with transaction.atomic():
            for product_id, quantity in cart.items():
                ShoppingCartItem.objects.get(user__id=user_id, product__id=product_id).update(quantity=quantity)
```

Using `transaction.atomic` all updates will be grouped into a single transaction. This will optimize Database interaction, if we have huge number of updates.